# Writing long hexadecimal value directly into the pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory, hex

So lets say I have a hexadecimal value like "77726974696E672068657820746F206D656D6F7279". I want to malloc a void pointer enough for that and write this directly into the memory.
I tried something like that but didn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    void* surprise; surprise = malloc(22);
    *surprise = 0x77726974696E672068657820746F206D656D6F7279;
    *((char*)(surprise+21)) = '\0';
    
    printf("%s\n", (char*) surprise);
}
```

I got these errors and warnings:

```
main.c:15:5: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
     *surprise = 0x77726974696E672068657820746F206D656D6F7279;
     ^~~~~~~~~
main.c:15:17: warning: integer constant is too large for its type
     *surprise = 0x77726974696E672068657820746F206D656D6F7279;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:15:5: error: invalid use of void expression
     *surprise = 0x77726974696E672068657820746F206D656D6F7279;
     ^
```

So as far as I understand it first converts hexadecimal value to integer and then writes it in memory but I don't want it. There must be a way to write binary or hexadecimal directly into the memory, we're talking about C but I couldn't figure it out and couldn't find any answers in internet. Btw, I'm trying to hide a string so it'll be a bit surprise for my friend.

Comment: C doesn't support arbitrary-length integers, but you can put this data in a char array, e.g., `char surprise[22] = '\x77\x72\x69\x74\x69\x6e\x67\x20\x68\x65\x78\x20\x74\x6f\x20\x6d\x65\x6d\x6f\x72\x79';`

Comment: @r3mainer You need to use double quotation marks for a string literal.

Comment: You cannot use arbitrarily wide constants in C. Look into your compiler's documentation to learn about the widest integer type.

Comment: @thebusybee That's true